# Javascript :Not able to Click on href containing javascript function within in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to click on an Intake link in my application coded in the following fashion:-

```
`<li id="menu-item-intake">
 <a href="javascript:parent.PopUpIntakeWizard(true);">
 <span>INTAKE</span>
 </a>
 </li>`
```

I need some help, first of all, to find an element and then click on it using the Cypress automation tool.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Some more details:- 
[Cypress Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bujxK.png)

[Want to click on Intake present in the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCMWE.png)

[HTML script of Intake link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9veN2.png)

Note:- This element lies inside the frame, maybe that is the reason it is not able to access it.

Comment: Please try to provide an actual code snippet

Comment: Have you tried using the Cypress element selector tool?

Comment: I would think you would be able to go cy.get('#'menu-item-intake').click(), can you provide more info on your actual test?

Comment: _“This element lies inside the frame, maybe that is the reason it is not able to access it.”_ - likely, because https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136 says currently it can not work with elements inside iframes, so frames presumably are the same issue. However, the suggestion from https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136#issuecomment-248619707 should be easily modifiable to work with frames instead as well, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks @misorude , I could make it work, the real problem was indeed to select an element inside the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could do this. Please provide more info about your actual test code.

```
cy.get('#menu-item-intake').find('a').click().
```

Comment: thank you for taking out time to take a look, Tried all suggestions but every time I am getting the same error, please see attached hyperlinks in the description. I hope the details are clear.